# show that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^k\;k!\;S(n,k) = (-1)^n$ using a combinatorial proof

Tags: combinatorics, induction

Prove that $\forall\ n \in \mathbb{N}$ , $$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k\; k!\; S(n,k) = (-1)^n.$$ 
Give a combinatorial proof and *don't* use 
the identity $$x^n = \sum_{k=0}^n S(n,k)(x)_k$$ where $$(x)_k = x(x−1)(x−2)\cdots (x−k+1)$$

**Proof:**

Recall that $S(n,k)$ is debited as the number of partitions of $[n]$ into $k$ nonempty boxes, where $S(n,k)$ denotes a the Stirling number of the second kind.

Where we have that $S(n,k) = S(n-1,k-1) + k \; S(n-1,k)$.

Then we will prove by induction that $\forall n \in N$ , $$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k\; k!\; S(n,k) = (-1)^n\tag{*}$$

To see this we show the following steps

**Base Case:**

When $n = 1$, we clearly have $-1 = -1$, which is equal and so the this is true for $n=1$.

**Inductive step:**

Let $n \in N$ be given and suppose $(*)$ is true for $n$. Then we want to show it's true for $n+1$.

Then 
By induction:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k}k!\left\{n+1 \atop k\right\}=
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k}k!\left\{n \atop k-1\right\}+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k}k!\left\{n \atop k\right\}k=$$

$$
=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k}k!\left\{n \atop k\right\} -(-1)^n (n+1)!+ \sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k}k!\left\{n \atop k\right\}k=$$  = 
$-(-1)^n (n+1)!+\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k}k!\left\{n \atop k\right\}+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k}k!\left\{n \atop k\right\}k$ .

basically after this, I am stuck.

However I am having trouble simplifying.  Can someone please help me with the inductive step.  Thank you.
I am also learning the inclusion-exclusion principle. I don't know if I could apply this. But I was thinking to prove it in an inductive way .

Comment: induction is a combinatorial proof?

Comment: I don't really know. I was thinking induction, but I don't know. I was trying to write out what I have so far.

Comment: can someone please help?

Comment: The formula $$x^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}k!\left\{n \atop k\right\}(x)_k$$ can be derived combinatorially. Is this unsatisfactory? i.e. Why do you not want to use this formula?

Comment: I am told not to use it. It would be easier of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By induction:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k}k!\left\{n+1 \atop k\right\}=
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k}k!\left\{n \atop k-1\right\}+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k}k!\left\{n \atop k\right\}k=$$ $$
=-\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k}(k+1)!\left\{n \atop k\right\}+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k}k!\left\{n \atop k\right\}k=$$ $$
=-\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k}k!\left\{n \atop k\right\}k-\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k}k!\left\{n \atop k\right\}+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k}k!\left\{n \atop k\right\}k=-(-1)^{n}
$$
I left the details to you.

Comment: I will try to understand it and maybe as you questions in a bit. Thanks

Comment: Answer looks good to me! (+1)

Comment: could you please check my updated attempt? I am having trouble understanding the second row from your answer.

Comment: The second row results from reindexing the first summation so that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^k k!\left\{n \atop k-1\right\}$$ becomes (using $k'=k-1$) $$\sum_{k'=0}^{n}(-1)^{k'+1} (k'+1)!\left\{n \atop k'\right\}$$ but note $\left\{n\atop 0\right\}=0$ for $n>0$. Then (after relabelling again $k'=k$) this term splits up since $(k+1)!=(k+1)k!$ and the first sum cancels the last because $\left\{n\atop n+1\right\}=0$. This leaves the middle term $$-\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^k k!\left\{n \atop k\right\}=-(-1)^n=(-1)^{n+1}$$.